# After a "deleteFromDocument" on an input in Chrome, the input's value does not update

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, dom

**UPDATE**

I discovered the real issue is that **the value of the input does not reflect the deletion**.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/BKj22/2/

**Original Post**

I have an input element that has text in it and I've highlighted some of that text. `selection.rangeCount` shows as `1`, so it sees the selection. I can also print out the selection and it prints it correctly (for example if I selected `"this"` it has that in `selection.toString()`). But `deleteFromDocument` does nothing and it says it's collapsed.

How do I fix this?

**This is fired from a `mousedown` event on a DIV**

```
var selection = window.getSelection();

//Try to delete from selection
if ( selection.rangeCount > 0 )
{
    console.log( selection.toString() );
    selection.deleteFromDocument();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
}
```

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/BKj22/1/

Comment: @Blender I discovered the problem and real issue. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the different ordering of mouse events and keyboard events. They fire as follows:

***Mouse:***

1. mousedown
2. mouseup
3. click

***Key:***

1. keydown
2. keypress
3. keyup

So in my "click" I considered the event complete, and in the "keypress" I was checking the value but it wasn't set until "keyup". I was tripped up by the different order in key and mouse events.

*Those difference are correct and make sense once you think about them. People expect that holding down a key repeats the key, the press needs to occur even before a "keyup". But no one expects holding down a mouse will continue to press the button multiple times.*